# Python - attribute error layoutparser GVCAgent

Tags: python, ocr

I got the following error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-0eb2b15f541e> in <module>
----> 1 ocr_agent = lp.GCVAgent.with_credential("<path/to/your/credential>",
      2                                        languages = ['en'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\layoutparser\file_utils.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    224             value = getattr(module, name)
    225         else:
--> 226             raise AttributeError(f"module {self.__name__} has no attribute {name}")
    227 
    228         setattr(self, name, value)

AttributeError: module layoutparser has no attribute GCVAgent
```

After running

```
ocr_agent =
layoutparser[ocr].GCVAgent.with_credential("<path/to/your/credential>",
languages = ['en'])
```

I previously run

```
import layoutparser as lp 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
```

And

```
pip install "layoutparser[ocr]"
```

Could anyone help me in this matter?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please, post the full traceback you get. By any chance is your file named `layoutparser.py`?

Comment: @buran I updated my question with the full traveback, for the file I don't think its name is `layoutparser.py` but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as well but just managed to solve it by typing this in the command line:

```
python -m pip install -U "layoutparser[ocr]"
```